# remapping command key + w to <Nop>

Tags: vim

When I press `'command key' + w`, I want to perform 'no op'. Unconsciously when I mean to type :w to save my file, I am pressing 'command key plus w' so my window is closed without saving my work. Just to avoid this problem, I remapped my `command key + w to <Nop>` but this mapping is not working, so the window is still getting closed. Can someone help with this mapping that I have currently in my .vimrc?

```
nnoremap <D-w> <Nop>
```

what is missing here? if there is otherway to achieve this goal that I should not lose my window when I press `command-w`, please let me know.

Comment: Use the tips on this page to remap terminal applications close window keys to something else: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/44412/229384

Comment: You can only fix unconscious mistakes consciously.

Comment: I should have said unintentionally or mistakenly .. it sounds funny after reading your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the MacVim GUI, `<D-w>` is not handled by Vim so you can't `:map` it or `:unmap` it at all.

If you are using the TUI (MacVim or not), the command key is completely invisible to Vim anyway, so `<D-anything>` will never work in that context.

So… the only way to prevent mistakes caused by your sloppy typing will be to fix your sloppy typing.

Comment: haha okay ..thanks for clarifying, so I don't have to spend time making it work.